# GCC not warning although it should

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have a very simple Hello World program, that doesn't have a return at the end of its main() function. If I understand correctly, this should throw a Wreturn-type warning, but when I compile it, no output at all is given. It simply compiles it and is done.

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

compilation commmand:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o hello.o hello.c
```

I also tried specifically with the `Wreturn-type` option.

On Manjaro 18.0.0 with GCC 8.2.1

Comment: "If I understand correctly, this should throw a Wreturn-type warning,..." No, it should not. With C99 this is optional. Your expectation is not correct.

Comment: As can be [seen on the gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards): "The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu11`."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic ...
```

because in C99 [1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.1.2.2.3) `main()` does not need a `return 0;`. It's as if there was one right before the closing brace.